# How to get all sub-Collection from firestore in react native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I want to get list of all sub-Collection from firestore:

```
Chat (col):

     0NzkNYBCqrVsUfORWksdc8bMj7J2 (doc):

          Here, I want to get list of all sub collections
```

I can access sub-Collection individually but i cant get list of collection.

Comment: There is no API to list (sub)collections in the client-side SDKs for Firestore. You'll have to either *know* collection names (i.e. hard-code) them or load them from somewhere (i.e. store them in a document).

Comment: @AbdulSaboor, you may be interested by this article: https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166